# UITextField minimum fontsize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm using the property `minimumFontSize`

```
textField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
textField.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
textField.minimumFontSize = 10;
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

But the text never goes to minimum font size of 10, it gets truncated, but if I change the current fontSize to 10, the whole text appears correctly. Am I using this property wrong?

Answer (score 19):

As late as it is ... you were setting up your `UITextField` correctly, and `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` does work in general, but I believe iOS is being underhanded.

It appears text in a `UITextField` will not automatically shrink beyond **14 pts*** - no matter if you set `minimumFontSize` to less than that value, such as your reasonable request of 10 pts.

A `UITextField` with:

- Font size 17, minimum size 15 will go down to 15 if need be
- Font size 17, minimum size 10 will only go down to 14
- Font size 13, minimum size 4 will stay at 13

You can test this by comparing three `UITextField`s side by side with strings of text far too long for them, where the minimum font sizes are 13, 14 and 15 respectively. The first two will appear exactly the same, at 14 pts.

It seems an odd magic number, but there you go. Iron-fisted readability considerations? I suppose you could try [adjusting the font size yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16356147/4522315) or living with having `minimumFontSize = 14`.

*I verified this in the IB but it will surely apply to programmatically created `UITextField`s too.

Answer (score 0):

The font will get truncated until the minimum font size. To experiment with this, drag a UILabel in Interface Builder, set the properties in there and change the width of the UILabel to see the effect.

Comment: Yes, that is the expected effect, but I have a UITextField in a UITableViewCell, that the text never gets to the minimun size. I can see the text getting smaller as I type, but not small enough to get to the minimum size

Comment: It should do. Have you linked it up properly? Or you could try setting it in IB.

Comment: Have you tried this (after calling your minimumfont code): `[theLabel sizeToFit];`

Comment: Original poster was referring to a UITextField, not a UILabel. adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth seems not to work for text fields.