# UITextField is cutting off the right side of text and not displaying the cursor at the correct position

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

This problem can be demonstrated by creating a new project in Xcode (I am using version 6.4) and using the following code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField * myTextField;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, self.view.frame.size.width-100, 50)];
    self.myTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    self.myTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]
    self.myTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.myTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:40];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myTextField];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.myTextField.text = @"1.5241578750119E18";
}
```

When running this project in iOS Simulator (iPhone 5 or 5S), the cursor is initially displayed after the last "1", and the "8" is not visible until a new character is typed.

This appears to be a bug by Apple, but my question is: is there a workaround for now that will force the text to right-align and show the cursor in the correct position?

To clarify the question further, the issue occurs when the text is set programmatically.  I expect to see this:

[image: Note that in this picture the entire number is showing (the last "8" is visible)]

But instead I am seeing this (note that the entire number is not visible and the cursor is showing after the "1" instead of the last digit which is an "8"):

[image: Note that in this picture that the last "8" is not visible.]

Comment: This question actually isn't very clear.  When you say the cursor is not in the "correct position", what is the position you expect the cursor to be in?  If the text field is full of numbers, shouldn't the cursor start off at the end of that field?  Or do you prefer the cursor to be somewhere else?

Comment: After even further research (and after filing another bug report with Apple), I came across this previous answer which I have implemented and appears to be working.  Posting here as reference in case someone else comes across this with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16356147/955853

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, existing in iOS, since iOS 7. Issue can be reproduced in stock applications like Settings as well. It affects text fields only when  `NSTextAlignmentRight` is used. The original bug ID logged into Radar for this issue is **14485694**. You may use centre or left text alignments, to circumvent this problem.

I would also suggest to file a new [bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) report to Apple,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
self.myTextField.leftView = paddingView;
self.myTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

it will add some space to the left side of your `TextField` so that your cursor starts at correct position.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I change your code to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
        self.myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, self.view.frame.size.width-10, 50)];
    self.myTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    self.myTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.myTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.myTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:60];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myTextField];
}
```

And start typing in those numbers, the cursor ends up along the right edge of the text field just as it's supposed to.

Even when I start the app with the default value in the text, I see the cursor along the right edge of the text field fine.

Comment: The issue is that if the textfield is set programmatically (I do this in viewDidAppear: self.myTextField.text = @"1.5241578750119E18") the cursor is displayed between the last 1 and the last 8, whereas I expect the cursor to be displayed after the last 8.  And in addition, the last "8" is not visible.  If you type in the numbers with the keyboard, the problem goes away.  So the problem occurs only if the text is set programmatically.

Comment: When I run your code with my modified `viewDidLoad` function that prepopulates the field to "`1.5241578750119E18`" on my iPhone 5S simulator, I'm seeing both the 8 and the cursor flashing after the 8 before I type anything.  Your problem appears to be that you've hit an edge case to what the UITextField and the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` can handle and that's why you are seeing the missing character.  You should adjust your code to match my "`viewDidLoad`" function and provide your code as a bug to apple via http://bugreporter.apple.com. They'll probably assign it a priority 3 or 4 to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Listening to `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` notification instead of `UIControlEventEditingChanged` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, try add dummy code like this

```
(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    textField.text = textField.text;
});
}
```