# Set a minimum font size for UITextView?

Tags: swift, uitextview

On a `UILabel` or `UITextField`, one can set a minimum font size to which the font will shrink if it does not fit otherwise in the element.

Is there an equivalent for this on a `UITextView`, and if not, is there a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399573/cant-get-uitextfield-to-autoshrink-the-font

Comment: yeah, um uitextview not uitextfield @shota

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27115350/6080920