# How to get all the textfields from a view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I have a view which has more than 15 `UITextFields`. I have to set bottomBorder(extension) for all the `UITextFields`. I can set it one by one for all the `UITextFields` and its working too. I want to set the bottom border for all the `UITextFields` at once. Here is the code I am trying but it seems like that for loop is not executing. I have even tried it in `viewDidLayoutSubViews` but for loop not executing there too.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /** setting bottom border of textfield**/

    for case let textField as UITextField in self.view.subviews {
        textField.setBottomBorder()
    }
}
```

Comment: try this `self.view.subviews.filter({$0 is UITextField}).forEach({$0.setBottomBorder()})`

Comment: Can't use it cause my extension is of "UITextField" type. My extension won't be available for view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made it working, but still need the explanation **why the code in question is not working**
I got it from somewhere on the forum, not exactle able to credit the answer.

```
/** extract all the textfield from view **/
func getTextfield(view: UIView) -> [UITextField] {
var results = [UITextField]()
for subview in view.subviews as [UIView] {
    if let textField = subview as? UITextField {
        results += [textField]
    } else {
        results += getTextfield(view: subview)
    }
}
return results
```

Call the above function in viewDidLoad or viewDidLayoutSubviews.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

/** setting bottom border to the textfield **/
    let allTextField = getTextfield(view: self.view)
    for txtField in allTextField
    {
        txtField.setBottomBorder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Code, part 1, add the "}" at the end. 
*Swift 5*. Works.

Answer (score 18):

**Swift**: This function will return all text-fields in a view. No matter if field exists in any subview. ;-)

```
func getAllTextFields(fromView view: UIView)-> [UITextField] {
    return view.subviews.flatMap { (view) -> [UITextField] in
        if view is UITextField {
            return [(view as! UITextField)]
        } else {
            return getAllTextFields(fromView: view)
        }
    }.flatMap({$0})
}
```

**Usage:**

```
getAllTextFields(fromView : self.view).forEach{($0.text = "Hey dude!")}
```

Generic Way:

```
func getAllSubviews<T: UIView>(fromView view: UIView)-> [T] {
    return view.subviews.map { (view) -> [T] in
        if let view = view as? T {
            return [view]
        } else {
            return getAllSubviews(fromView: view)
        }
    }.flatMap({$0})
}
```

Usage:

```
 let textFields: [UITextField] = getAllSubviews(fromView: self.view)
```

Answer (score 3):

extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func viewOfType<T:UIView>(type:T.Type, process: (_ view:T) -> Void)
    {        
        if let view = self as? T
        {
            process(view)
        }
        else {
            for subView in subviews
            {
                subView.viewOfType(type:type, process:process)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
view.viewOfType(type:UITextField.self) {
        view in

        view.text = "123"
}
```

Comment: This is super flexable and very easy to use!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
for aSubView: Any in self.view.subviews {
if (aSubView is UITextField) {
    var textField = (aSubView as! UITextField)
    textField. setBottomBorder()
}
}
```

or try this

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
if (view is UITextField) {
     var textField = view as! UITextField
      textField. setBottomBorder()
}
}
```

Comment: I think that there is no need for the first code snippet.

Comment: Not working, control is jumping out from the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
for view in self.view.subviews as! [UIView] {
    if let textField = view as? UITextField {
        textField.setBottomBorder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
var textFieldsArray = [UITextField]()

for view in self.view.subviews {
    if view is UITextField {
        textFieldsArray.append(view as! UITextField)
    }
}

textFieldsArray.forEach { $0.setBottomBorder() }
```

If you want to get the result of the function applied in a new array, use map() instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
func getTextFields() {
    for textField in view.subviews where view is UITextField {
       (textField as? UITextField).setBottomBorder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5
A Very simple answer you can understand easyly
: - You can handle all kind of Objects like UILable, UITextfields, UIButtons, UIView, UIImages .  any kind of objecs etc.

```
for subviews in self.view.subviews {
    if subviews is UITextField
    {
        //MARK: - if the sub view is UITextField you can handle here
        funtextfieldsetting(textfield: subviews as! UITextField)
    }
    if subviews is UIButton
    {
        //MARK: - if the sub view is UIButton you can handle here
        funbuttonsetting(button: subviews as! UIButton)
    }
    if subviews is UILabel
    {
        //MARK: - if the sub view is UILabel you can handle here
        //Any thing you can do it with label or textfield etc
           
     }
 }
```