# Hide something in all objects of the same class

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, static-methods

I'm trying to hide a UILabel in every object (UIView) of the same class in my app. I tried something with a static class method but I'm not able to access to the instance variable.

**MyView.h**

```
@interface MyView: UIView
{
    UILabel *titleLabel;
    UILabel *subTitleLabel;
}

+(void)hideLabel;

@end
```

**MyView.m**

```
#import "MyView.h"

@implementation TempNodeView

    +(void)hideLabel
    {
        [titleLabel setHidden:YES];
    }

@end
```

What is the best (proper) solution in this kind of situation?

Thank you very much

Comment: just try to get all the labels from View & hide it! Please check below link , here is example for getting all textfields from view but you can replace UITextField with UILabel - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908471/how-to-get-all-the-textfields-from-a-view-in-swift

Comment: There is no magic way of acting on all instances of a class without having a reference to those instances. You could have your class instances observe an NSNotification and hide the label when that notification is posted.

Comment: Ok, but what if I have several labels and I want to hide only one kind of label?

Comment: What do you mean with "one kind of label"?

Answer (score 1):

For your case I suggest you to have references to all of this objects. This means you will need to add the object into some static array in its constructor.

The problem then occurs that the views will be retained by the array so you need another object that will be a container for a weak reference to your object so you avoid memory leak.

Try to build something like the following:

```
static NSMutableArray *__containersPool = nil;

@interface MyViewContainer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyView *view;
@end

@implementation MyViewContainer
@end

@interface MyView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UILabel *labelToHide;
@end

@implementation MyView

+ (NSMutableArray *)containersPool {
    if(__containersPool == nil) {
        __containersPool = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return __containersPool;
}

// TODO: override other constructors as well
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        MyViewContainer *container = [[MyViewContainer alloc] init];
        container.view = self;
        [[MyView containersPool] addObject:container];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (void)setAllLabelsHidden:(BOOL)hidden {
    for(MyViewContainer *container in [[self containersPool] copy]) {
        if(container.view == nil) {
            [[self containersPool] removeObject:container]; // It has been released so remove the container as well
        }
        else {
            container.view.labelToHide.hidden = hidden;
        }
    }
}

@end
```