# UITextField adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth not working

Tags: ios, uitextfield

On iOS 7, `textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES` has no effect. `minimumFontSize` is also properly set. I expect that font size will be reduced if text is too long to fit in textField's frame.
But, what actually happens is that text gets clipped and "..." gets appended on the end.

I tried:

- Setting width constraint for textField
- Setting font for textField in places other than init method of the containing view

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Code is a bit convoluted, but here it is:

```
self.captionView = [[CaptionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, 50)];
self.captionView.textField.font = [self.captionView.textField.font fontWithSize:20.f];
self.captionView.textField.leftPadding = 2.f;
self.captionView.textField.rightPadding = 2.f;
self.captionView.textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.captionView.textField.minimumFontSize = 2.f;
self.captionView.captionViewDelegate = self;
[self addSubview:self.captionView];
```

`CaptionView` has property textField, which is a subclass of `UITextField`.

This subclass overrides methods:

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
 - (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect;
 - (CGRect) editingRectForBounds: (CGRect) bounds;
 - (CGRect) textRectForBounds: (CGRect) bounds;
```

EDIT:

I just commented out each of these overrides, and font is still not adjusted well.

EDIT:

Most similar question I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350045/cant-get-uitextfield-to-autoshrink-text).
And the accepted answer was to give up on using `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: If it still isn't working without those overrides, are the left and right padding properties still doing anything? Does the problem go away if you use a vanilla UITextField instead of your subclass?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextField minimum fontsize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045176/uitextfield-minimum-fontsize)