# UITextField subclass messing adjustFontSizeToWidth

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikit, subclass

I've created a subclassed textfield view inside my view controller, with the font size to **15**, the AdjustFontSizeToWidth enabled and the **minimum font size to 10**.
My textfield has a placeholder text too big to fit the view. The adjust font size to width is activated and the system is reducing the size of the font to **14**. I don't exactly know why **14**, because the placeholder still doesn't fit (see screenshot)
Any idea why is this happening ? Did i missed something ?
I subclassed UITextfield and override the following methods (Not sure it is relevant, but this seem to be methods who may cause this bugs) :

```
- (CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
CGRect leftViewRect = [super leftViewRectForBounds:bounds];
if ([self shouldShowLeftView] == YES) {
    CGFloat newHeight = self.frame.size.height * 0.5f;
    if (self.leftImage) {
        leftViewRect.size.width = newHeight;
    }
    leftViewRect.origin.x = kMargins;
    leftViewRect.origin.y =  (self.frame.size.height - leftViewRect.size.height) / 2.0f;
 }
 return leftViewRect;
}


- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
CGRect rectForBounds = [super textRectForBounds:bounds];

if ([self shouldShowLeftView] == YES) {
    rectForBounds.origin.x += kMargins;
    rectForBounds.size.width -= 2.0 * kMargins;
} else {
    rectForBounds.origin.x += kMargins / 2.0;
    rectForBounds.size.width -= 2.0 * (kMargins / 2.0);
}
return rectForBounds;
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
CGRect rectForBounds = [super editingRectForBounds:bounds];

if ([self shouldShowLeftView] == YES) {
    rectForBounds.origin.x += kMargins;
    rectForBounds.size.width -= 2.0 * kMargins;
} else {
    rectForBounds.origin.x +=  kMargins / 2.0;
    rectForBounds.size.width -= 2.0 * (kMargins / 2.0);
}
 return rectForBounds;
}
```

[image: placeholder not fitting in the screen]

EDIT: Update, I tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16356147/1324369)
 and adapted the code a bit to make it work for the placeholder also. The font resizing is fine, but the UI is messed up when the text is reduced, the text offset itself to the left, behind the left image view. On the screenshot, we can see that the right margin is too big and the text too much on the left.
[image: Screenshot fail new try]

Comment: There is a system minimum font size. UITextField will not shrink the font size as far as you are hoping.

Comment: My minimum font size is 10, and the placeholder has a font with 14pt instead of the 15 I gave by default, it is probably miscalculated. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't missing anything - this is a quirk of iOS. `minimumFontSize` values less than 14 seem to be completely ignored as per [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30881385/4522315) to a similar question.

Set your original font size to 300 and the `UITextField` will still be 14 pt, not 10 pt.

14 is an odd magic number; undocumented, but probably used to maintain readability. If only it could be lower.

Comment: ... and I guess 14 is the minimum system font size matt mentioned.

Comment: @Cowrin Newall Thanks for your answer ! I didn't know about this. I tried the solution you mentioned on your other answer, adapted it a bit but this solution seem buggy and adjusting the font cause bad placement caused by apple methods. When i resize my text, the text is drawn behind my left image. Any idea why/ how to fix it ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in the Apple Docs it says not to call `textRectForBounds:` directly, and the sample code does.
Are your constraints setup correctly etc etc? Not quite sure what your new problem looks like.

Comment: @Loadex "The default implementation of this method returns a rectangle that is derived from the control’s original bounds, but which does not include the area occupied by the receiver’s border or overlay views." I assume it doesn't allow for your phone image either.

Comment: I call it only to get the values of the text bounds. Should not be a problem. I will edit my post to add a screenshot of my new problem.

Comment: I suspect the text bounds are altered by autolayout to adjust for your Phone image, but the value returned by `textRectForBounds:` does not change accordingly, leaving a Phone-sized 'margin' on the right side.

Comment: I think so too, but i have no clue about how to fix that. The margin grows more and more as I reduce the text though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80761/discussion-between-loadex-and-corwin-newall).