# textView rotation error

Tags: ios, rotation, textview, uitextview

I am developing an app with TextView.

If you increase the font size, rotate the TextView and save it to the album, you will get white lines like images.

Is there a solution?

```
UIView *trueView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 900, 1070)];
[trueView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
trueView.clipsToBounds =YES;


UITextView *textView2 = [[UITextView alloc]init];
textView2.text = @"abcdefg";

textView2.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding =0;
textView2.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
textView2.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textView2.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
textView2.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
textView2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textView2.accessibilityLabel =@"0";
textView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView2.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
textView2.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

textView2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;


textView2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:300];
[textView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(6,  415, 895, 369 )];

UIView *textView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6,  415, 895, 369)];
[textView addSubview:textView2];

textView2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90);

[trueView addSubview:textView2];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(900, 1070),NO,1);
CGContextRef trueContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(trueContext,0, 0);
[trueView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *originalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(originalImage, self, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? (take a look at [mcve]* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the width of the `textView` when you rotate it as it will clip the edges. Just increase the width and adjust accordingly.

Another solution would be to automatically resize the text to allow it to always fit regardless of the size by setting a **minimum font size.**

See this thread on `TextView` minimum font sizes
[UITextField minimum fontsize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045176/uitextfield-minimum-fontsize)

One other thing to note is, if the textView will only be a single line, you are better of using a `textField` which will allow you more access to things like truncation, minimum font sizes and clipping etc.

Comment: Check this out from the iOS11 version.