# UITextField shrinks text before necessary

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a `UITextField` for which I've set `autoAdjustFontSizeToFitWidth` to `true` and `minimumFontSize` to `0`. The problem is the setting shrinks the text noticeably sooner than it really should. For example, here is an image of a `UITextField` with the above settings:

[image]

The green is the background color of the `UITextField`. In this example, the text has not shrunk yet, but no matter what I type as the next character the text field always begins shrinking; despite clearly being enough room on the left side for a few more characters. Here is another image with additional characters entered:

[image]

As you can see, there is a relatively large area on the left side that the text field won't place text in when auto adjusting. This is for a right aligned text field. The same can be said of center aligned text fields as well, where there is space on the left *and* right that seems as if an auto adjusting text field won't place text inside.

How do I get it so that auto adjusting text fields use the entire available space?

Comment: Do you happen to have leading padding? Or possibly skipped setting the alignment to leading? To me it looks like the space to the left, is the same regardless of text size.

Comment: you may have set leftView for the uitextfield...

Comment: @xTwisteDx The only padding that would be there is whatever's there by default, and as far as I know `UITextField`s don't have default padding; or at least certainly not that much.

Comment: @FahimParkar I haven't, but furthermore the area only goes unutilized when the `autoAdjustFontSizeToFitWidth` is set to `true`. When it's `false` the area gets utilized albeit when the text is too long for the field the ellipsis then appear.

Comment: what is linebreak mode you have? I think you have byWord. try by byChar...

Comment: @FahimParkar `UITextField`s don't support setting a line break mode.

Comment: Show the code or sample project

Comment: You should add your code....

Comment: As is evidenced by [@de.'s answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73028063/6744473) this is a problem that affects `UITextFields` universally, so there is nothing specific about my code that would illuminate the problem as the problem is not within my code but within the iOS SDK.

Comment: I've tried multiple things to recreate your issue and the only way I was able to recreate it was by adding a leftView to the UITextField. What is your XCODE version?

Comment: Please see my updated answer for a non-hacky solution.

Comment: @shoe bounty grace period is about to end. Did my answer solve the issue for you?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

You can do the text calculations and font resizing manually. By doing so you will avoid hacks and future compatibility issues.
A simple implementation looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    var originalFont: UIFont!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.textField.font = self.textField.font?.withSize(44)
        self.textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
        self.originalFont = textField.font
        self.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)

    }

    @objc
    func textFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
        
        let textRect = sender.textRect(forBounds: sender.bounds)
        let textWidth = textRect.width
        
        var currentFont = self.originalFont!
        var i = 0
        while (i < 10) {
            let unrestrictedTextWidth = sender.text!.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude,
                                                                               height: textRect.height),
                                                                  attributes: [.font : currentFont],
                                                                  context: nil).width
            if unrestrictedTextWidth <= textWidth {
                break
            }
            
            let factor = textWidth / max(textWidth, unrestrictedTextWidth)
            let originalSize = currentFont.pointSize
            currentFont = self.originalFont!.withSize(originalSize * factor)
            i += 1
        }
        sender.font = currentFont
    }
}
```

Interestingly the actual relationship between text rect and font size is non-linear and non-trivial. So I added multiple iteration steps to approximate the correct size. I chose a maximum of 10 iterations to avoid infinite loops on very small sizes and rounding errors.

**Original Answer:**

There has always been some magic around `UITextField` and `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`. See for example this post from 2015 about how the initial font size affects the minimum font size:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30881385/921573

> A UITextField with:
> Font size 17, minimum size 15 will go down to 15 if need be
> Font size 17, minimum size 10 will only go down to 14
> Font size 13, minimum size 4 will stay at 13

In my tests, setting the minimum font size in IB to 0 just gets ignored – in order so see the shrinking effect it has to be a small value like 1.
Setting it in code to 0 works fine.

So I think it is safe to say that `UITextField` might be considered historically buggy when it comes to `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`.

That being said, I found a workaround for you:

```
class FixedTextField: UITextField {

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        let magicNumber = -15.0
        
        if self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth {
            return CGRect(
                x: bounds.origin.x + magicNumber,
                y: bounds.origin.y,
                width: bounds.size.width - magicNumber,
                height: bounds.size.height
            )
        } else {
            return super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
        }
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return self.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
    }
}
```

This custom text field uses countermagic to mitigate the issue.
You may have to play with the magicNumber according to your font or dimensions or device. For me 15 works ok:

[image: text field fixed]

Comment: So this would work until Apple addresses the problem; at which point all my text displays that implement this solution would be cut off. Thanks, but it doesn't really seem like a wise solution.

Comment: Hasn’t happened since 2008.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and the `textField.textAlignment` is set to `.right` (it will depend on how many characters you put in the textField though) :

[image]

```
class TextFieldOne: UITextField {


override func alignmentRect(forFrame frame: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    
  //  let newWidth = frame.width + 10 // if you want to reduce the right side too.
    
    let x = frame.origin.x - 15 // suit yourself here
    
    let newFrame = CGRect(x: x, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    
    return newFrame
    
   
}


override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
       return self.alignmentRect(forFrame: self.bounds)
    }


override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return self.alignmentRect(forFrame: self.bounds)
     }



}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this answer suffers from the same dilemma that @de.'s does and that's if Apple fixes the bug in the future then, without notice, every single text display that implements this hack will have its text cut off throughout the entire application. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't come with such a risk.